# Deploying Laravel 5.2 to a shared hosting sub domain

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, laravel-5

I have uploaded the files to a sub-domain I am however struggling to deploy them. The Larevel files sit in a folder called virtual in the user folder and the public files in a folder called virtual in the public folder.

Paths:

```
/home/name/virtual/

/home/name/public_html/virtual/
```

I have edited the index.php to:

```
require __DIR__.'/../virtual/bootstrap/autoload.php';


$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../virtual/bootstrap/app.php';
```

I am however getting the following error message.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting
identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in
/home/snips11/public_html/virtual/index.php on line 50
```

Line 50 references the $app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check what version PHP you're running. Laravel requires `>= 5.5.9` and likely you are not meeting those requirements, which will generate this error.

From the docs:

> - PHP >= 5.5.9 <-- (Likely your issue.)
> - OpenSSL PHP Extension
> - PDO PHP Extension
> - Mbstring PHP Extension
> - Tokenizer PHP Extension

More information about required specs can be located in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/installation).